# React Typescript Antd Table (expandedRowRender) filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm trying to filter my Language Lines to each no column, but it just print all Language data into all Lines:

EDIT:
[image]

And this is the Code for the Columns:

```
const expandedRowRender = (record, index, indent, expanded) => {
            const columns = [
                {
                    title: "Sprache",
                    key: "no",
                    render: () => {
                        return (
                            <Space direction="vertical">
                                <Text>{record.de}</Text>
                                <Text>{record.en}</Text>
                            </Space>
                        );
                    },
                },
            ];
            return (
                <Table
                    columns={columns}
                    dataSource={this.state.question}
                    rowKey={(record) => record.no}
                />
            );
        };

        const columns = [...]

        return (
            <Table
                className="components-table-demo-nested"
                columns={columns}
                expandedRowRender={expandedRowRender}
                dataSource={this.state.question}
                loading={this.state.isLoading}
                rowKey={(record) => record.no}
            />
        );
    }
```

Now it print 4 times the same Language data (beacuse the array has 4 entries). But why is it doing this? It should just print it 1 time.

Here is my sample data:

[image]

Comment: Please put the sample data of StaticRange.question here if you can

Comment: @HDM91 I added the sample data

Comment: is it staticrange.question data that you passed to inner table or not? could you please add full data that pass to table

Comment: @HDM91 sorry for the misunderstanding, I pass the state question into the table. I dont know why stackoverflow converted my code here into "MediaRecorder" and "staticrange"... So this.state.question is an Array of my Model Question with the data that you can find in the picture above. Each Record has an Translation "de" and "en", and with the example code of you the Table prints now the right Translation but four times becuase the passed Array contain four items.

Comment: now you can filter the array based on record.no or index, I dont understand why you pass both table same array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`expandedRowRenderer` has arguments that you can use for filtering your inner table based on parent table data.

```
    const expandedRowRender = (record, index, indent, expanded) => {
      //you can use record here to filter datasource
      columns = [
        {
          title: "Sprache",
          key: "no",
          render: () => {
            return (
              <Space direction="vertical">
                <Text>{MediaRecorder.de}</Text>
                <Text>{MediaRecorder.end}</Text>
              </Space>
            );
          },
        },
      ];
      return (
        <Table
          columns={columns}
          dataSource={this.StaticRange.question.filter(q => q.no === index}
          rowKey={(record) => record.no}
        />
      );
    };
```